# Get attribute of a node with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem concerning XSL.
From a CMS System I get the following output:

```
<custom name="email"><link title="Send email" href="mailto:some@exmple.com">some@example.com</link></custom>
```

I want to output an "a" attribute based on that. I'm using the following XSL Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- <custom name="email" pretext="Some custom text"><link title="Send email" href="mailto:some@exmple.com">some@example.com</link></custom> -->
<xsl:template match="custom[@name='email']">
    <div class="custom email">
        <span class="icon custom email"></span>
        <p>
            <span class="pretext"><xsl:value-of select="@custom:pretext"/></span>
            <a href="{link/@href}"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to output:

```
<div class="custom email">
    <span class="icon custom email"></span>
    <p>
        <span class="pretext">Some custom text</span>
        <a href="mailto:some@example.com" title="Send email">some@example.com</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

But I don't get it working... My problem is that I'm not able to get the "href" attribute from the "link". Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curly braces to get xpath evaluated as attribute values. Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent='yes'/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="custom">
    <a href="{link/@href}"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></a>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the below XML when ran against the above XSLT:

```
<custom name="email"><link title="Send email" href="mailto:some@exmple.com">some@example.com</link></custom>
```

gave the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a href="mailto:some@exmple.com">some@example.com</a>
```

Doesn't it solve the problem of getting `<a>` with @href?

Comment: Unfortunately not... I edited my base post and added my wohle template. But I don't get any output on the "a".

Comment: Well the answer I provided tells you how to get the "<a/> element with href. Now, your template has <span/> element where I can see a prefix "custom" for @pretext and your input XML doesn't seem to have any namespace declared for this prefix. You can edit your question with the complete XSLT and we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I got it now. The thing is, that there was a <paragraph> tag before the <link>. So the right solution is {paragraph/link/@href}. That one works. Thank you.